# Read string on Browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to read a string that will be written in my browser just that I only write it 5 in 5 seconds necessary to recover the value of it while it is being written.

Here's my code to write in php:

```
 set_time_limit(0);
       // $this->layout = null;
        $i = 0;
        for($i; $i<10;$i++){
            echo 'Line '.$i."\n";

            flush();
            ob_flush();
            sleep(3);
        }
        echo 'LOOL';
```

Now, how do I read this with JQuery or other solution?

Comment: `id="test"` will be duplicate !

Comment: I know it a test only. But I can't read a value of string while the for don't finished.

Comment: @TamasPap I got a get value of string, not a html generated;

Comment: @Kefka, I think you can't achieve this from php directly. As Kurosh mentioned you need to go for an AJAX method if you are not building a command line program.

Answer (score 1):

for read contents in JQuery you need to use DOM style, you can change the result to something like this :

```
echo "<div id='myid".$i."'></div>
```

and now this code is readable for JQuery, then in JQuery you can access to this ID with code like this :

```
$('#myid1').click(function(){$(this).hide);});
```

Comment: Um, but in my "for" would generate 10 lines. And that I need to get each line as it is written and not at the end of execution. In case there is a sleep 3 seconds. Every 3 seconds I should have a line. How do I get it before it is written to another?

Comment: Aha, so you should change your code, it's not a good way to use php like this, you can use AJAX and do that every 3 seconds in client side and then fetch your result with AJAX if you have server side contents. i hope i understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side code. Once it has been sent to the client, it can no longer update the page, and it returns the whole page generated as an HTML page.

It means it Does not `echo`es **anything** before finishing the request.

(in this case) it takes 30 seconds to php `echo`es **10 lines**.

if you want to do that, as  @Mehdi Hosseini said, you must create an Ajax request in every 3 seconds and show your response after a request .